# Compound Annual Growth Rate returning Invalid floating point operation occurred

Tags: sql, sql-server, math

I am attempting to calculate the compound annual growth rate. Certain values work without any issues, but one particular set of numbers (along with some others) is generating an error:

> Invalid floating point operation occurred

I have tried various attempts at casting the values, but am still getting the error.

```
SELECT CAST( POWER (
CAST((0.2142 / -1.38613) as float),

CAST(1 as float)/(2015-2012)

) as float) - 1
```

Based on some calculations by hand (unless I'm being a complete idiot), I would expect the result to be -1.5366261528... I am also not too concerned with rounding after 4 decimal points.

Comment: Quite an interesting bug you stumbled upon.  O_o F.e. `POWER(-1.0E0, 2.0E0)` and `POWER(1.0E0, 2.1E0)` both work, but `POWER(-1.0E0, 2.1E0)` crashes.  I wonder if a mathematician could come up with a work-around formula for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is imaginary numbers.  When you can raise a negative number to the power of 1/3, then you get a negative number with no imaginary part.

However, 1/3 cannot be perfectly expressed as a float.  When you raise a negative number to 0.3333333333, then you get an imaginary number -- and these cannot be expressed as a float.

Can you do the operation with a positive base for `power()`?

Comment: I figured it was the negative number, was hoping there was a way to move past it like Excel does, but I am just going to toss out any negative values.